# Django - aggregate and annotate for simple operations

Tags: python, django

I see in the docs the aggregate and annotate functions can be used to create a new column in the query, so if I write something like:

```
my_object = ...objects.filter(something).annotate(extra_column=Avg(value))
```

the inner query will give an extra column

```
, AVG(value) AS "extra_column" ...
```

Now, it seems to me that it can be used only will functions like count, avg, max, and min... can I do something as a simple +/- certain number?

I'm trying `.annotate(extra_column=another_column+1)` or `.annotate(extra_column='another_column'+1)` but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Could you close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions for arithmetic. `F()` is part of [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#query-expressions). From the documentation:

> Django supports addition, subtraction, multiplication, division,
>   modulo arithmetic, and the power operator on query expressions, using
>   Python constants, variables, and even other expressions.

A code example is:

```
from django.db.models import F

my_object = Model.objects.annotate(extra_column=F('another_column') + 1)
my_object = Model.objects.annotate(extra_column=F('another_column') * F('yet_another_column'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate functions do return the integer which could be manipulated by adding, subtracting etc.

The following example works on **Django 1.11.6**:

```
from django.db.models import Count
employees = Employee.objects.annotate(managers=Count('manager') + 10) # every employee has only a single manager.
print employees[0].managers # prints out 11
```

Comment: yes, but... I don't need to _count_ anything. Why the hurry for the close? lol. I'm out of the work for the weekend